# Cloud datastore client.GetAll type mismatch but client.Get works

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a `go` application in `app engine` that connects and returns some info from `datastore` entities. I'm having an issue where `client.Get` is working with a predefined struct but `client.GetAll` is throwing a type mismatch (or vice versa).

I am using the following struct with both:

```
type myStruct struct {
    ID              int64
    Field1          string
    Field2          string
    Release_Date    time.Time
}
```

This works when `Release_Date` is defined as `time.Time` (fails if `int`):

```
k := db.datastoreKey(id)
myStruct := &myStruct{}
if err := db.client.Get(ctx, k, myStruct ); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("datastore: %v", err)
}

func (db *datastoreDB) datastoreKey(id int64) *datastore.Key {
    return datastore.IDKey("myEntityType", id, nil)
}
```

This fails when `Release_Date` is defined as `time.Time` (works if `int`):

```
var myStructs []*myStruct 
q := datastore.NewQuery("myEntityType").
            Project("field1", "field2", "release_date").
            Order("field1")
keys, err := db.client.GetAll(ctx, q, &myStructs)
if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("datastore: %v", err)
}
```

The error:

> datastore: cannot load field "release_date" into a "myStruct": type mismatch: int versus time.Time

(or vice versa when I swap the `Release_Date` definition).

Any ideas what is wrong or is this a bug?

**Additional info:**

I've looked at the entity dashboard and there it lists the data type as `Data/Time` and when I retrieve the entity with `Get` it loads fine into the struct and I can use the object in my code.

I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure that *every* record has a release_date that is a time.Time?  that seems like the most likely cause - there actually *is* a record (or records) with an int for that field, and there actually are records with a time.Time, so no matter which one you choose, when you do `GetAll`, it fails, since it will find at least one that doesn't match.

Comment: I did check (I'm only testing with three entities right now) and just double-checked to be sure. All are the same data type.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help -- it still looks like either @dave is right about the entities not all having been stored in the same way, or possibly that you have two different entity types.  We don't see how you create your key (`k`) in the `Get` example, so we don't know if that's using the same `"myEntityType"` as the `GetAll` example.  One way or another, though, we know from your error messages that you've stored some entities' `Release_Date` as `int` and some as `time.Time`.

Comment: Also, I've never seen `NewQuery`, `Project`, or `Order` with lower-case parameters, since they only work with exported types and fields.  I'm not sure if the datastore package just treats them case-insensitively (since these are just string parameters referring to things you've already stored, that's entirely possible), but it stands at to me as unusual, and incongruous.

Comment: I added where I create `k`. I also nuked all entries in my datastore and added a single entry (fun fact, it means you have to rebuild the indexes) triple-checking the data types. The parameters you refer to are the named fields in my datastore so they should match case, no?

Comment: Well, the struct fields are exported/capitalized: `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Release_Date`, and you're using the parameters: `"field1", "field2", "release_date"`.  Again, I don't know if that's actually an issue; it just stands out as non-standard (and possibly an issue).  In any case, I recommend updating with a single-file minimal reproducible example.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you've posted.  It could turn out that you have two different `myStruct` types in different packages, or any number of things like that, that we just can't identify based on what we can see here.

Comment: @tmwoods Can you confirm if what Darshan Rivka Whittle stated in the last comment was the issue?

Comment: @komarkovich No, I don't believe it was. I'll add my process as an answer, although it's not a very good solution. It's based more on a theory than fact, although it would be easy to test and reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't an elegant solution, but it's what worked for me.

What I *think* was the cause is that the very first entity I created had a field `Release_Date` of a type `int` but I later added entities using the type `Date/Time`. During my testing I had ended up removing the entity with type `int` for `Release_Date` so the only remaining entities had `Date/Time`. Despite having no entities with type `int` for `Release_Date`, my code failed server-side. It kept expecting that field to be of type `int`.

My theory is that the entity definition was established when I first created the entity and was not updated when I changed the data type later on even though no entities remained using type `int`.

So what I ended up doing was backing up my entities, removing ALL of them, then re-adding the entities with only `Date/Time` in the `Release_Date` field. Once I did that, everything worked fine. I still have the casing the same as shown above (i.e. my `Struct` uses `Field` but my query uses `field`).

This would likely be an easy thing to reproduce but I haven't gotten around to it. If anyone else gets around to testing please add a comment, otherwise I will eventually and submit a bug report.